# How to display latex code in div from a textarea?

Tags: php, jquery, string, latex

In [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com) and [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com), whenever someone writes a text like

```
some text $equation1$ some text $equation2$ ...
```

in a textarea, the text is displayed in a box below formatted with LaTeX.

Does anyone know how this can be done? I mean which tool is used and how to render the equation in a div and how to avoid rendering it in a textarea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/). You can read about how to use it at your website reading [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html) and syntax examples [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Usage example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</body>
</html>
```

Renders as:

[image: result]

[Demo](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-tex.html)

**EDIT:** If you don't want to render the math equations in one textarea, you can mark the element with an specific class like: `math-editor` and configure MathJax as:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
      ignoreClass: "math-editor" // put this here
    }
  });
</script>
```

This `ignoreClass` property is explained [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html). Or you could use the `processClass` property to mark what *should* be processed.

Also, you can bind the textarea with a jQuery function to capture the event when the user types something inside the textarea to copy the text and paste at another div that can be rendered by MathJax.

**EDIT2**: another [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/M7FUEsxNYsOfndgLMFZY?p=preview) showing how to update a div with rendered code after inputing plain text in a textarea.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to process only one class?

Comment: I'm not sure. You'll need to test. I believe that if you add  `processClass: "my-div"` it will render only the div with this class and the processor will forget about the rest. If this is not the behavior, you can add `ignoreClass: "my-ignored-div"` to avoid the rendering at your textarea.

Comment: Just one last question: if you see the code I just added to my question, why is the div no longer processed when I change its content? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user3741635, see this demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/M7FUEsxNYsOfndgLMFZY?p=info  You need the `MathJax.Hub.Typeset();` call to reprocess the div.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.